# magento 2.3.3 review not showing on product page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2, review, debugging

I migrate Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.3.2 everything is working fine but review not showing on the product page, even its total number of reviews on the product and the stars as well, also show in the widget but not appearing under reviews tab, review form also working fine.

Any solution thanks in Advnace ?

Answer (score 1):

it was causing issue with the Amasty Custom tab Extension I just disabled it and reviews starting working thanks for your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your review Rating is Active and your store is selected or not.

Select your store and Active your review Rating.

Check [this link](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-manage-review-rating-magento-2.html)